# Select query populates datagridview but NULLS integers, why?

Tags: vb.net, excel, datagridview

My datagridview is populated by an excel worksheet (by using select * from $Sheet1), Most values are inserted in the datagridview (most are strings) but integer only values are nulled

[image: first image]

Example of nulled queries

[image: second image]

This is how i populate my datagridview

```
Private Sub btnimportStdntList_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnimportStdntList.Click
        OpenFileDialog1.Title = "Please Select the excel file with the list of question"
        OpenFileDialog1.FileName = "listofquestion.xls"
        OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel Sheet(*.xls)|*.xls|All Files(*.*)|*.*"
        OpenFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "C:temp"
        OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
    End Sub
    Private Sub OpenFileDialog1_FileOk(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles OpenFileDialog1.FileOk
        Try
            Dim strm As System.IO.Stream
            strm = OpenFileDialog1.OpenFile()
            txtQuestionList.Text = OpenFileDialog1.FileName.ToString()
            cn = New OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='" + txtQuestionList.Text + "';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;")
            cn.Open()
            FillDataGridView("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]")
        Catch myerror As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(myerror.Message)
        Finally
            cn.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub
    Private Sub FillDataGridView(ByVal Query As String)
        da = New OleDbDataAdapter(Query, cn)
        dt = New DataTable
        da.Fill(dt)
        With DataGridView1
            .DataSource = dt
        End With
    End Sub
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: May you check the content of an integer of datatable cell, e.g.  dt.Rows[0][2] ? Is it equal to DBNull.Value ?

Comment: Tried adding this

`If (e.RowIndex >= 0) Then
            If IsDBNull(DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value) = True Then
                MsgBox("TRUE")
            Else
                MsgBox("FALSE")
            End If
        End If`

Blank cells returns true

Comment: Please check datatable to isolate the problem either on DataTable load or Datagridview display. The code mentionned seems ok. So I rather see the problem coming from datagridview events. If you definded some event handlers, may you show their code?

Comment: No event handlers on the datagridview, the code above is 90% of total code in the form (excluding imports and connectionstring)

Comment: Try to modify the Extended properties in your connection string as follow: _"Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1;"_